# multiple labels on webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two arrays , one with values that I need to display on labels on webpage and the other with positions of the labels. I have 54 labels on webpage with label names  "lb1,lb2,...lb54"

suppose

```
int [] values = {21,22,18,16,17.........22}

int [] positions = {12, 1,3,5,54,.........8}
```

Now I need to display "values" on labels with corresponding positions. the positions array describe the order in which values are to be assigned. so label 12 should have 21, label 1 should have 22 and so on...

I tried this by running a loop and couldn't get it..

```
for (int j=1;j<=54; j++)
{
    getLabelID("label" + positions [j].toString).Text = Convert.ToString(values[1]);
}
```

Comment: 54 labels named lb1..lb54? This should go straight into _thedailywtf.com_, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

First Array are 0 index based, so your loop should start from 0 to <54 or Array Length

And There is no toString property for getting string, there is ToString() method for getting string value. so `positions[j].toString` will be `positions[j].ToString()`

and you are always getting the 2nd element from your value array by using `values[1]`, it need to be change to `values[j]`

Your loop should be like

```
for (int j=0;j<positions.Length; j++)
{
    getLabelID("label" + positions[j].ToString()).Text = Convert.ToString(values[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing brackets from the end of ToString(). Try:

```
for (int j=1;j<=54; j++)
{
    getLabelID("label" + positions [j].ToString()).Text = Convert.ToString(values[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code - based on LINQ operator

```
var controls = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList();
foreach(Label item in controls)
{
     var index = Convert.ToInt32(item.Id.ToString().Replace("label","").Trim());
     var text =  Convert.ToString(values[index]);
     System.Console.WriteLine(text);
     item.Text =  text;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it is giving error with the Id, it says no extension method "id"

Answer (score 0):

and if you don't want to have "54" hardcoded, you can do something like this :

```
positions.ToList().ForEach(
  p=>getLabelID(String.Format("label{0}",p)).Text=values[p].ToString()
);
```